# What is the maximum RAM size for MacBook Pro Mid 2012?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, memory

To improve the performance of my mid-2012 MacBook Pro, I upgraded to a 256 GB SSD. But, I also want to upgrade my RAM. What is the limit that this computer supports?

Comment: You might want to add your model number to your question to make sure the answers are applicable.  See [ask] for tips.

Comment: @fsb, Doesn't matter what Mid 2012 MacBook Pro model as all three can handle 16 GB RAM

Comment: @user3439894 The reason for my comment was to help a new user understand the best way to ask questions here.

Comment: Have a look at: [Crucial 16GB Kit (2 x 8GB) DDR3L-1600 SODIMM Memory for Mac](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/macbook-pro-%2813-inch-and-15-inch%2C-mid-2012%29/CT3373650)

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for the suggestion. I've already ordered that and it's shipping next week. In the product page, they wrote that Crucial supports my MacBook for this RAM. But when I controlled the official Apple page, they only insert 8. Asked the question for this.

Comment: @fsb thanks for your help about teaching me writing a new post. I'm new here (as you know) so I need some tips. I have a blog but blog and a forum is a different thing. Next time I'll provide more info. Thanks for helping...

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, they can all support 16GB. However, one of the mid-2012 models came with onboard RAM and no memory slots. It does support 16GB as long as you purchased it that way. So, if the OP had this particular model, they wouldn't be able to upgrade the RAM.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Mid 2012 MacBook Pro can support up to 16GB of RAM by using 2 8GB kits. Both the Retina and non-Retina models (mid 2012) support 16GB of RAM.

Per [EveryMac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.7-15-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html), you can have [image]

I have personally used the [Kingston KVR16LS/8](http://radnex.us/Kingston_PC3-12800_8GB_KVR16LS11) modules many times with great results.

[image]

Since, you said that you already upgraded your drive to an SSD, I assume you know how to remove the bottom cover to access the memory.

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks for the answer. I've read an article that is located on the Apple Support Communities website and they say that my MacBook pro only supports 8 GB of RAM but you can insert an 16GB one but it will not give the best performance. I've already ordered [link] (https://www.amazon.com/Crucial-DDR3L-1600-SODIMM-Memory-CT2K8G3S160BM/dp/B008LTBJFW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1477055101&sr=8-1&keywords=macbook+pro+mid+2012+ram) 2 kit RAM last week but it takes a long time shipping.

Comment: Yeah, I know removing the back cover. Thanks for the edited answer @Allan :D Appreciate it.

Comment: No problem...Do you know if you have a Retina or the non-Retina mid 2012?

Comment: You said, "_The Retina model can only support up to 8GB of RAM._", the MacBook Pro Retina 15" Mid 2012 ships with either 8 or 16 GB PC3-12800 (1600 MHz) DDR3L on-board memory. See : [MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2012) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp653?locale=en_US)

Comment: @Allan of course, it's the non-retina one.

Comment: @user3439894 - that was an error that I already fixed.  I misread the late 2012 and caught my error when I double checked.

Comment: @ArdaÇebi - I edited my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: @Allan, When I read the answer the information was as I quoted it and was not yet fixed, stop making excuses, I commented so you'd correct it, that's all and you did!

Comment: @ArdaÇebi - about your first comment - can you confirm if you did get issues about performance? Thanks

Comment: @Allan did you use `Kingston KVR16LS/8` to upgrade an old mac?

Comment: As far as I remember, yes @ManuelJordan

Comment: @Allan Thanks for the feedback - about the first comment written in this post - about _but it will not give the best performance_ Did you get that experience? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ManuelJordan… More RAM doesn’t speed up your Mac.  What it will do is if you find that macOS is writing to Swap because you’ve run out of RAM, it will give your applications more real estate in which to operate and thus not slow things down.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance - I am going to buy a SSD (currently it has HDD) - and I want take the opportunity to upgrade the RAM too.

Comment: RAM Is a very inexpensive way to get more out of a computer @ManuelJordan.  Good luck with it!

Comment: For the audience, the upgrade was possible successfully, now the mentioned MacBook Pro has 16GB

Answer (score 6):

Your question doesn't specify which model of MacBook Pro (Mid 2012) you're asking about and the answer may be different depending on model. I summarise this below:

**MacBook Pro (15", Mid 2012)**

This model has two memory slots capable of taking 204-pin PC3-12800 (1600 MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM memory chips. Officially (i.e. according to Apple) these models only support 8GB of RAM. However, real world tests have proven that they can actually support 16GB of RAM.

See these [MacBook Pro: How to remove or install memory](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201165) for instructions.

**MacBook Pro (Retina, 15", Mid 2012)**

This model has no memory slots and came with either 8GB or 16GB of onboard memory installed. You cannot upgrade the memory on this model.

**MacBook Pro (13", Mid 2012)**

This model has two memory slots capable of taking 204-pin PC3-12800 (1600 MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM memory chips. Officially (i.e. according to Apple) these models only support 8GB of RAM. However, real world tests have proven that they can actually support 16GB of RAM.

See these [MacBook Pro: How to remove or install memory](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201165) for instructions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't matter what Mid 2012 MacBook Pro model as all three can handle 16 GB RAM

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer Monomeeth. I'm currently new in this community and I need learn some writing basics. I'm currently improving myself about this subject. My mac was the third (MacBook Pro 13", Mid 2012). I've ordered one through amazon last week, a 2 8GB kit to enable. I will use them. Thanks for the answer again.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, they can all support 16GB. However, one of the mid-2012 models came with onboard RAM and no memory slots. It does support 16GB as long as you purchased it that way. So, if the OP had this particular model, they wouldn't be able to upgrade the RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently visited an Apple Store in San Antonio to deal with my mid-2012 Retina version of the 15" MacBook pro.  He said their Apple service center does not even sell RAM anymore for this model but he recommended Crucial and he said it will definitely support 16gb RAM.