# Is my RAM compatible with my Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I have a **Mid 2012 13-inch MacBook Pro**. To speed it up, I bought  two Kingston PC3L-12800 **1600 MHz** memory modules which have **4 GB** each. However, my computer keeps showing the famous "beach ball" if try to do to many things at the same time (keeping multiple tabs open, closing applications one after another etc).

Do you think there is a compatibility issue? If so, is there a way that I can solve it?

Comment: Did you already install them? Does the computer boot up? If you go to “about this mac…” home much ram does it say you have?

Comment: Yes, it recognizes the modules properly. However, when I do many things on the computer, the system just locks down. The screen freezes and I have "beach ball" instead of the regular mouse cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a problem:

**PC3L ≠ PC3.**

PC3L is PC3 Low Voltage memory that operates at 1.35V and PC3 operates at 1.5V.  The 2012 MacBook Pro calls for PC3-12800.  See [Everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.9-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html).  For best results you want to use the exact memory, or [higher quality memory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258151/119271) that [operates at both voltage levels](https://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR16LS11_4.pdf).

Also, that Mac is capable of 16GB of RAM, and the price point is low enough that you could max it out for only a marginal amount more.  Nobody ever said "Gee I have too much memory!" It's better to have and not need than need and not have!

Comment: So are my RAMs completely useless or is there a method that I can make them work?

Comment: You can't force memory to use higher voltage - it either is capable of it or it isn't

Comment: Alright, thank you for the quick reply! @Allan

Comment: @FrenkFrenk One might note that the RAM is completely useless _to you on your MacBook Pro_.  But because someone manufactured them, they'll fit...something.