# Can the mid 2012 Macbooks have their CPU upgraded?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory, cpu

I have an old MacBook Pro that I found laying about my house and it is specifically a MacBookPro9,2. I am aware that I can upgrade the RAM to 16GB DDR3 and that I can convert the hard drive to SSD; but I am wondering if there are other parts of the laptop that I can upgrade like the CPU, fan, or something of that nature if at all possible.

If someone could shed some light on this, I would be grateful.

Comment: The only Macs with changeable CPUs are desktop Mac Pros.

Answer (score 2):

No, you’re not able to upgrade the CPU as it is soldered to the main logic board. You can see it in photo (red box).

**Mid-2012 MacBook Pro Unibody (MacBookPro9,2)**
[image: mid 2012, MacBook Pro unibody logic board]

**Mid-2012 Retina (MacBookPro10,1)**
[image: Mid-2012 MacBook Pro logic board]

<sup>Images sourced, from [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2012+Teardown/11225)</sup>

Do you want to upgrade the processor, then you must change the entire main logic board.

The fan is a standard laptop fan; I don't believe that there is a more "performance" version for this component.

The SSD is upgradeable in the non-retina models.  It uses a 2.5” “laptop” drive.  Since it’s SATA, any aftermarket 2.5” SSD will work.  The Retina model uses a proprietary M.2 connector.  Technically it’s upgradable, however, being proprietary, you’re limited to used/salvaged SSD modules; aftermarket  SSDs are generally not available.

RAM is not soldered on the mid 2012 MacBooks; it can be upgraded to 16GB RAM. See, the post [What is the maximum RAM size for MacBook Pro Mid 2012?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258151/119271) for more details. RAM is soldered on to the logic board on the Retina models. It is not upgradable.